# Accidentally sent BCC to q Address, not Legacy

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I accidentally sent 0.25 BCC from coinspot to my wallet but I entered the qAddress. I noticed it didnt go through so checked through their help forums and found a post saying that you need to use legacy addressed to correctly transfer funds. Are my funds lost or can they recover them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't related to Bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing by q-address, you mean cashaddr. If coinspot accepts those, you will receive the BTC. If they don't, they completely incompatible with the regular Base58 addresses, and if coinspot tried to treat it as one they wouldn't be able to build a valid tx.

You should contact coinspot if you coins don't show up in your wallet.

Comment: Yes I mean cashaddr. Coinspot seem to only be able to send to a legacy address. Will they be able to recover the coins or are they lost?

Comment: If they don't support cashaddr, the coins never left coinspot. No recovery is needed, they simply need to credit them back to your account.

Comment: Thank you, support finally got back to me and said they'd add a message stating that they dont support cashaddr for future reference

Comment: @Maverick they should do more than that. They should validate addresses users enter and if they are invalid or unsupported they should display an error message and refuse to send the coins there. Expecting users to follow up with support over such trivial matters is silly.